# How can I fix the problem that a MenuItem takes on the ID of a previous one

Tags: java, android, xml

At the beginning I have two items and the 2nd gets a listener with:

```
final View view = findViewById(R.id.list_item);
                if (view != null) {
                    view.setOnLongClickListener(v -> {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Long pressed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return true;
                    });
                }
            }
```

But if I add a new item with `menu.add("name");` the listener is on the newly added item and not on the old one (list_item)

I have already tested many other alternatives, but they don't work!
I just need help on how to keep the item ID or how the listener stays on the item.

Comment: You should use `onCreateOptionsMenu` & `onOptionsItemSelected` to inflate & set a click listener to a menu respectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add an item using ``menu.add(...)` it returns a reference to the newly added item. You can set the listener like this:

```
    final MenuItem newItem = menu.add("New item");
    newItem.setOnMenuItemClickListener(menuItem -> {
        // Handle your click here!
        return true;
    });
```

However, you should add/remove menu items by overriding `onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu)`. When you use `menu.add(...)` use the overload that allows you to set the `itemId`:

```
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        menu.add(Menu.NONE, 314159, Menu.NONE, "New item");
        
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```

Note that the above will be called each time the menu is going to be shown (very convenient).

Then you can handle the menu being selected from `onOptionsItemSelected`:

```
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getItemId() == 314159) {
            // Handle menu selection here!
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Check the AppBar/Menu guide here: https://developer.android.com/training/appbar